# First GridViewColumnHeader Not Receiving Custom GridViewColumnHeaderStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have been developing a Wpf project, that includes a DfcListView class (that inherits from a ListView class). In the file 'DfcListView.xaml', I have the following code to define DfcListViewGridViewColumnHeaderStyle (a GridViewColumnHeader style):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataFlowControls">

    <Style x:Key="DfcListViewGridViewColumnHeaderGripperStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}"></Style>
    <Style x:Key="DfcListViewGridViewColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}"></Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then, in the xaml file 'Generic.xaml', I have:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataFlowControls">    

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>        
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/DataFlowControls;component/Themes/DfcEditCheckBox.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/DataFlowControls;component/Themes/DfcEditComboBox.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/DataFlowControls;component/Themes/DfcEditTextBox.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/DataFlowControls;component/Themes/DfcListview.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

This code works fine, except the first GridViewColumnHeader in a resultant DfcListView does not receive the DfcListViewGridViewColumnHeaderStyle. All other grid view column headers receive the DfcListViewGridViewColumnHeaderStyle. **How could I amend the code, so that the first GridViewColumnHeader also receives the DfcListViewGridViewColumnHeaderStyle?**

I've read some other articles on stackoverflow.com regarding these sorts of issues, and I haven't been able to determine a solution from them.

Answer (score 0):

I just worked out that it works if I delete the following from the code (see code above):

x:Key="DfcListViewGridViewColumnHeaderStyle"